# Check if an object is null (Shortest way)

Tags: php, yii2

I try to check if an object is null.
In **Groovy** I can check:

```
System.out.println(object?.object2?.property)
```

In other words

```
if(object != null){
    if(object.object2 != null){
        System.out.println(object.object2.property);
    }
}
```

Now I want the same in PHP
How can I write the same in the shortest way?

```
object->object2->property
```

object2 can be null
if I try to get the property of object2 I get a NPE

Thanks for help.

Comment: `<?php echo (isset($object) && $object->object2 != null)?object->object2->property:'null or empty'?>` that's all

Comment: Are you looking for `is_null()`? Or simply put it in an `if` `if(object->object2->property)`

Comment: My problem is that object2 can be null, if object2 null I get an exception cause I try to get a property from a null object

Answer (score 2):

in version `8` of `PHP` you can use `Nullsafe` operator as follow:

> ```
> $prop = object?->object2?->property;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
if( ! $object)
if($object !== null)
```

If you're using PHP7 you can also do null coalesce operator

```
$object1 ?? $object2
```

in your case

```
if($object && $object->object2)
```

Comment: Can you remove one equal from if statement `!==` not correct

Comment: it's saver to also compare the type, therefor two equals

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function over the entire object

```
if (isset($object->object2->property))
    echo 'It exists!';
else
    echo 'It does not exist!';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi We have a function is_null() or isset()

```
if(isset(object, object->object2)){

        echo(object.object2.property);

}
```

Comment: what do you mean not php? isset() allow  multiple vars to test

Comment: @volkinc `isset` is php, but `System.out.println` is Java. Plus, in php you use `->` instead of `.` to access properties of a class.

Comment: in a question was asked for  PHP and Yii

Answer (score 0):

If you're still using PHP 7, I made a helper that you can use.

```php
if (!function_exists('nullSafeObject')) {
    function nullSafeObject($object, ...$parameters)
    {
        if (!is_object($object)) {
            return null;
        }

        $result = null;
        foreach($parameters as $parameter) {
            if (isset($object->$parameter)) {
                $result = $object->$parameter;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```